# Getting a 504 Gateway Error on Google App Engine (long runtime of Flask App)

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have been working with Google Cloud Platform & Flask for the first time - my client wanted me to deliver a solution on it in 2 weeks.
I have been successful so far in creating a Flask application and wanted to productionize it through Google App Engine. However, the runtime of my function is a little over 2.5 minutes and I get a **"504 Gateway Timeout"** error. In the code piece, I am accessing bigQuery, google spreadsheets and GCS buckets. Should I switch to a new GCP service or can some tweaks in my code/yaml file suffice? My yaml config is -

```
runtime: python37

liveness_check:
 check_interval_sec: 300
 timeout_sec: 299
 failure_threshold: 10
 success_threshold: 10
 initial_delay_sec: 500

readiness_check:
 app_start_timeout_sec: 1800
```

I would be very, very grateful to anyone who can help me resolve this issue.
Thank you!

**Edit:** Just to give a brief about the application - this is a forecasting application that reads data from bigquery, GCS buckets, and Google Spreadsheets, processes it and runs ML models on it. The results are written back to Google Spreadsheets within the application itself (i.e. no response needed from the application per see). I'm triggering the application using google AppsScript.

Comment: is it AppEngine Standard or Flexible? Standard allows request to take max 60 seconds.

Comment: Not sure about that. Are you saying the standard would be better?

Comment: App Engine Standard is probably the wrong service for you. I would use Cloud Run instead. However, there are no details in your question about memory, CPU, storage, networking, etc requirements. Other options include App Engine Flexible and Compute Engine.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm pretty new to GCP so not sure how to extract details about the instance - would give flex a try. *fingers crossed*

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to restructure how your website works.  You can then stick with GAE standard.  Even if you switch to GAE flexible, it will work better this way.

Here is the sequence of operations:

1. A user submits a request from web page.
2. Your website returns immediately with a page that indicates that you are working on it.
3. The page you return includes Javascript that will poll your website to ask if the task is complete.
4. When the task is complete, the Javascript will update the page and present the results to the user.

On the server side, you can use cloud tasks for doing the processing which I believe has a time limit of 10 minutes.

This way, the user is always viewing a web page and isn't sitting there waiting and looking at a blank screen while waiting for the server to return something.